# UPDATE statement in an inheritance based table

Tags: sql

I've got a table that's meant to be used for modeling an inheritance relationship.  It's column oriented so have columns for all the properties and looks something like:

```
mainid, subid, prop1, prop2, etc.
```

all rows with the same mainid are related and any row with subid=0 is the parent to any row that matches mainid and subid > 0.  Thus:

```
100, 0, 'abc', 123

100, 1, NULL, 456
```

means that `(100,1)` is a child of `(100,0)` and that querying `prop1` for `(100,1)` should give me `'abc'` and querying for `prop2` for `(100,1)` should give me `456`.

This seems to work ok however, when I want to update `(100,1).prop1`, I'd like to make the field `NULL` if the update value is `'abc'` (matches the parent.prop1 field).  Is there a simple update query I can do for this? I realize I can do this over multiple queries but would like to do it for one update query and for updating many fields at once, if possible `(eg update (100,1).prop1='abc', (100,1).prop2=789, etc.)`

This should work for standard SQL (eg not something specific to any particular sql engine)

Comment: what database server are you using?

Comment: not possible, you can only update one row at a time.

Comment: @Hogan, I wish to only update 1 row (the child row) but that value should be NULL if the incoming value matches the parent, otherwise take the incoming value to be an override of the parent.  Thus trying to set (100,1).prop1='abc' would result in (100,1).prop1=NULL since (100,0).prop1='abc' whereas (100,1).prop1='xyz' would simply be 'xyz'.

Comment: @KashifQureshi - it's proprietary but SQL friendly :-)

Comment: does this proprietary sql friendly platform support the latest standards in windowing functions?

Answer (score 1):

Use a case expression and a dependent subquery, they are part of standard ANSII SQL and they are supported by almost all databases.:

```
UPDATE table t1
SET prop1 = CASE WHEN EXISTS 
                 ( SELECT * FROM table t2
                   WHERE t1.mainid = t2.mainid 
                     AND t2.subid = t1.subid - 1 
                     AND t2.prop1 = 'abc'
                 )
             THEN NULL ELSE 'abc' END
WHERE t1.mainid = 100 AND t1.subid = 1
```

Comment: nice.  any generic way to do this for N properties (updating prop1, prop2, etc.)?  also, does this invariably do 2 queries anyways?